# Different word orders in one sentence

Tags: grammar, word-order

In Duolingo, I faced the following sentence:

> Er ist schön, obwohl er alt ist.

What I don’t understand is why the verb is before the adjective in the first part of the sentence *(ist schön)* and behind it in the second part *(alt ist).* Is it correct? What is the reason for such a reordering?

Can I use the same word order in both parts of the sentence? For instance:

> Er ist schön, obwohl er ist alt.

Or is this word order totally wrong in German or changes the meaning?

Comment: Main clause: http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa032700a.htm – sub clause: http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa010910a.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German, the position of the (conjugated) verb has a grammatical function:

- In regular sentences, the verb is at the second position.
- In subclauses, the verb is at the end.
- In questions or commands, the verb is in first position – possibly preceded by a question or politeness particle.

In your example, *er ist schön* is the main clause and *obwohl er alt ist* is the subclause, hence the different word order. The alternative word order you are suggesting is wrong.

Something similar still exists in English (though it is somewhat archaic, if I am not mistaken):

> Had I not studied all night, I would have failed the exam.
>   Had I not swapped *had* and *I* at the beginning of this sentence, I would have had to use an *if.*

Note that beyond the position of the verb, word order is used for emphasis in German – though this does not apply here.